How to bridge fifths across 3 strings on violin/viola
I'm familiar with bridging a finger across 2 strings to play fifths and all of the weirdness that happens to get that in tune (fingers, it turns out have a certain roundness). I'm also aware that it gets harder for we of thin fingertips as the strings get farther apart (closer to the bridge). I've got some tough pieces that have relatively fast fifths across 3 strings in reasonable (below 7th) positions. I've tried doing a bridge on the notes played most and then re-placing for the "rarer" note, tucking another finger in beside and doing a shift to hit the last one, but I don't know the easiest way to play fifths across 3 strings. I'm trying to remove the intonation issues and the muddy sound of incompletely pressed strings - I want to clean it up because it goes fast. On a guitar, my hand is sideways enough to bridge 6 strings if I need to and I can envision a cellist or bassist getting their finger flat across the fingerboard, but violinist's and violist's hands would need to turn to what appears to be an extremely awkward angle.
Edit:
One such passage has quick, slurred (in SPN) A#3,B3,F#4,C#4 with long C#s on either end (4 then 5) I'd like in tune and with vibrato. A bar later, the motif repeats starting on D#4. I've tried a "rolling bridge" which is usually a bit flatter on the C# than the B and F#. I've tried shifting from the F# to the C# on the same string which makes it hard to avoid a glissando. A "barre" is really painful to get near to in tune, and seems drastic to do in sequence. My preference if I add a short shift would be to have the end note be single-finger rather than bridged because I want a nice, clean, easier vibrato on the longer note (which happens to be the same as the last note), so rather than 2-3-2-2, do 2-3-3-2. There are, obviously 3 half-step variations each shifting up and down.
What's the "easy" way to three notes that are all the same distance from the nut across 3 strings? Have I exhausted all of the options and I need to choose something and then get better, or is there something I'm missing?

Interesting. Could you edit to give actual musical examples? The answer might change if these are double stops, triple stops (heaven help us), or just consecutive single notes, and how any other fingers might be involved.

@AndyBonner I'm working on the first movement of the Walton viola concerto whose first quick passage comes to mind with multiple examples. Also, Bach's 5th cello suite scordatura (I think the second section of the courante). These happen to be consecutive notes, but I'm looking for solutions that are more general than what would happen for just one passage. What are the rules about posting passages like that? Also, I think I would have to input a picture, right (there's no builtin music markup)?

There is a notation plugin but it's too buggy to be much use. I typically just screenshot a pdf and paste the image directly into the editor; this hosts it automatically. Of course it's good to make sure that the images are publicly licensed, but it sure seems to me (as a non-lawyer) that screenshots of small excerpts for discussion purposes are fair use.

My initial answer is, no, unfretted instruments don't do "barre chords." It's almost always better to find some way around even trying, like the tricks you mention. I might do some experimentation before saying so absolutely. For the Walton, when I google images, I found one with penciled-in fingerings; for the "A# B F# C#" they did "2 3 2 2," taking the half step as a unit in half position, and the slurred notes as another unit in first position.

@AndyBonner The passage in question is right next to the 'Do not photocopy' message. As well, somebody I won't throw under the bus took a marker to it, so it's not high quality :-/ I assume, though, that this is a challenge in other pieces and much smarter people have figured it out
